# What causes early faith growth in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I am playing with Japan , it's very early, no Patheons, I discovered a natural wonder but it's nowhere near... and I just see I have +2.3 faith or so per turn. I wasn't paying attention when it started :/ What causes this?

Comment: Could be first contact to a religious citystate...

Answer (score 3):

As @kl78 rightly points out, the reason for my unusually high faith income was because I had contacted Yerevan, a Faith-Based City State.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/256497)

Comment: As this **is** the author, I don't think that was the intent. ♪ Perhaps a little more detail might be warranted about the mechanics of Religious City-States?

Comment: @Virusbomb It does provide an answer, although I do not blame you for not realizing as it is poorly worded. I'll make an edit to make what the answer is more clear

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources of faith in Civ 6 : Rise and Fall.  In approximate order of availability : Natural Wonders like Graceful Arch which add faith to neighboring tiles , Friendly Huts which provide faith upon entry , Envoys at friendly City-States , Holy Sites with adjacency bonuses , Holy Site buildings , World Wonders , civilization-specific Improvements like the Sphinx , City-state-specific Improvements like Colossal Heads , and a few others which come later in the game.

It's possible to find or create several of the above in the first 50 turns.  It's very good to be suzerain of La Venta.